# Does it make sense to model a Solr document if search does not allow to specify the attributes?

Tags: solr

I want to provide a search feature in my site where the user is able to search by text only, without specifying the attributes.

For example, instead of allowing the user to search by "author=George Martin" he will simply query "George Martin".

I would like to know if there is any advantage in a document model like this one:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "title": "Game of Thrones",
  "author": "George R. R. Martin",
  "published": "August, 1996"
}
```

Compared to:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "data": [
    "Game of Thrones",
    "George R. R. Martin",
    "August, 1996"
  ]
}
```

If I'm not going to use "author:value" in the Solr API, I should get the same results, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first version will allow you to assign different weights to the different fields. I.e. a hit in the title might be more important than a hit in the author field - or vice versa.

Using the edismax handler (`defType=edismax`) and query fields (`qf=title author published`) will give  you the same behavior as your second example, but will retain the structure of the document.

As the fields are put into the `qf` parameter, there is no need for the user to explicitly tell Solr which fields she wants to search.

To give the fields different weights, assign a weight to the field in the `qf` list: `qf=title^5 author^2 published` will give a hit in title five times the weight than a hit in `published` - i.e. "The Hunt for Red October" will be more important than something published in October.

Comment: Thanks! Your example with "October" in the title helped me a lot.